# AWS CDK Code Pipeline Development - error TS1005: ']' expected

Tags: typescript, aws-cdk, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild

**Problem:** I am building a `new CodePipeline` with the `aws-cdk-lib/pipelines` library in the CDK, and am facing a typescript error within the code build stage.

**Error Message:**

*Folder structure abbreviated*

```
[Container] 2023/01/03 07:48:21 Running command npm run build

> template@0.1.0 build
> tsc

intoMagentoQueueConsumer/node_modules/axios/index.d.ts(6,18): error TS1005: ']' expected.
intoMagentoQueueConsumer/node_modules/axios/index.d.ts(6,21): error TS1005: ';' expected.
intoMagentoQueueConsumer/node_modules/axios/index.d.ts(6,35): error TS1005: '(' expected.
intoMagentoQueueConsumer/node_modules/axios/index.d.ts(6,36): error TS1135: Argument expression expected.
intoMagentoQueueConsumer/node_modules/axios/index.d.ts(6,50): error TS1005: ')' expected.
intoMagentoQueueConsumer/node_modules/axios/index.d.ts(7,1): error TS1128: Declaration or statement expected.

[Container] 2023/01/03 07:48:36 Command did not exit successfully npm run build exit status 2
[Container] 2023/01/03 07:48:36 Phase complete: BUILD State: FAILED
[Container] 2023/01/03 07:48:36 Phase context status code: COMMAND_EXECUTION_ERROR Message: Error while executing command: npm run build. Reason: exit status 2
```

I have included the other error messages of TS1135 and TS1128 for context, as they all might be related.

**CDK Code Pipeline Stack:**

Note, in my commands, I `cd` into each Lambda, install it with `npm ci`, and then `cd` out. I'm removed this code as it is quite verbose. It was at the top of the `commands` key value pair. `tsc -v` results in the latest TypeScript version.

```
this.codePipeline = new CodePipeline(this, `${environment}-${appName}-`, {
  pipelineName: `${environment}-${appName}-`,
  selfMutation: true,
  crossAccountKeys: false,
  role: this.codePipelineRole,
  synth: new ShellStep("Deployment", {
    input: CodePipelineSource.codeCommit(this.codeRepository, environment, {  codeBuildCloneOutput: true }),
    installCommands: ["npm i -g npm@latest", "npm install -g typescript"],
    commands: [
      "tsc -v", 
      "npm ci",
      "npm run build",
      "cdk synth",
    ],
  })
});
```

**Lambda Function package.json:**

```
{
  "name": "intomagentoqueueconsumer",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@aws-sdk/client-sfn": "^3.226.0",
    "axios": "^1.2.1",
    "axios-retry": "^3.3.1"
  }
}
```

**Lambda Function Build in the CDK:**

```
this.intoMagentoQueueConsumer = new NodejsFunction(this, `intoMagentoQueueConsumer`, {
  runtime: Runtime.NODEJS_16_X,
  memorySize: 1024,
  handler: "handler",
  depsLockFilePath: join(__dirname, "../../src/lambda-handlers/queue-consumers/intoMagentoQueueConsumer/package-lock.json"),
  entry: join(__dirname, "../../src/lambda-handlers/queue-consumers/intoMagentoQueueConsumer/index.ts"),
  bundling: { 
    minify: false,
    nodeModules: ["@aws-sdk/client-sfn", "axios", "axios-retry"],
    externalModules: ["aws-sdk", "crypto-js"],
   },
});
```

***EDIT:*** I've changed the install command for typescript to `npm install -g typescript --save-dev` and obtained a Version of 4.9.4. This did not, however, fix the issue.

Comment: Which version of axios and typescript are you using?

Comment: @BrunoMarotta, `"axios": "^1.2.1"` and the latest version of TypeScript.

Comment: A Google search of the `axios/index.d.ts(6,18): error TS1005: ']' expected` error message returns many results.  The root causes seem to be various instances of package version incompatabilities.  Not related to CDK/Pipelines as such.  Does your code compile in _any_ environment?  If so, pin your dependency versions in `package.json` to the working combination.  This means removing the `^` in front of the version to specify an exact [semantic version](https://docs.npmjs.com/about-semantic-versioning).

Comment: @fedonev, I'm looking at "Application stages" and wondering whether adding this feature to build all the stacks would remove this error and future others. What are your thoughts? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/cdk_pipeline.html

Comment: @fedonev, also, will I need to re-create the package.json files locally before deploying do you think?

Comment: @fedonev, removing the "^" and re-creating the package.json before the code build didn't do anything.

Comment: `Stages` won't help.  Unrelated concept.  Is this a CodeBuild only problem? Does your code build locally?  Yes, the idea is to get a `package.json` with pinned dependencies that works everywhere.  You  commit it and `package-lock.json`.

Comment: Also note that dependency conflict is just a hypothesis.  A reasonable one, but unproven.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250805/discussion-between-luke-and-fedonev).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**To fix this problem:**

1. Ensure all `NodejsFunction` code refers to the root package.json file and DOES NOT have it's own package.json
2. Ensure the latest version of Typescript (mine was 4.9.4), is installed in the development dependencies.