# AWS CDK Code Pipeline Development - How Do I Install NodejsFunction Package.json Dependencies?

Tags: typescript, aws-cdk, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild

I'm trying to organise a `new CodePipeline` following the [documentation from the CDK V2](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.pipelines-readme.html#at-a-glance). My project has many instances of the `NodejsFunction`. Whilst Code Build can install the root package.json dependencies, I am struggling to find an organised solution for installing each package.json for each Lambda Function.

**Example Folder Structure:**

```
-Root
--src
---lambdaHandlers

----lambdaOne
-----index.ts
-----package.json
-----package-lock.json

----lambdaTwo
-----index.ts
-----package.json
-----package-lock.json
```

I require Code Build to go into each of these folders and install the `NodejsFunction` dependencies, to remove the Code Build Error Message of: `error TS2307: Cannot find module '@aws-sdk/client-sfn' or its corresponding type declarations`.

***Note:*** Everything works and deploys using cdk deploy --all.

**Code Pipeline CDK:**

```
this.codePipeline = new CodePipeline(this, `${environment}-${appName}-`, {
  pipelineName: `${environment}-${appName}-`,
  selfMutation: true,
  crossAccountKeys: false,
  role: this.codePipelineRole,
  dockerEnabledForSynth: true,
  synth: new ShellStep("Deployment", {
    input: CodePipelineSource.codeCommit(this.codeRepository, environment, {  codeBuildCloneOutput: true }),
    installCommands: ["npm i -g npm@latest", "npm install -g typescript"],
    commands: [
      "npm ci",
      "npm run build",
      "cdk synth",
    ],
  })
});
```

**One solution** I tried was using the code in the commands section of `this.codePipeline` below for each Lambda Function. Whilst this worked for installing the packages, I was left with typescript errors:

```
"cd src/lambda-handlers/api-gateway-entry-points/entryPointMagentoCredits", "npm ci"
```

**Error Received:** `intoMagentoQueueConsumer/node_modules/axios/index.d.ts(6,18): error TS1005: ']' expected.` [Full Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74990110/aws-cdk-code-pipeline-development-error-ts1005-expected)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution:**

1. There is no absolute requirement to go `cd` into each `NodejsFunction`
   folder and install the dependencies in the build command.
2. All `NodejsFunction` dependencies should be stored in the root package.json file
3. All the `NodejsFunction` handlers can be stored anywhere in the code, and referred to either with the `entry` key value pair, or be stored in the lib folder ([DOCS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_lambda_nodejs-readme.html#reference-project-architecture)).

**New File Structure:**

```
-Root
--lib
---lambda-Stack
----index.ts
----lambdaOne.ts
----lambdaTwo.ts

--package.json
--package-lock.json
```

I added the `depsLockFilePath` with reference to the package-lock.json file, but I am not sure whether this is necessary. ([DOCS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_lambda_nodejs.NodejsFunction.html#depslockfilepath))

Comment: THANK YOU! This has given me a headache for so long.
For others, if you are using `PYTHON` based cdk, make sure to put an `npm i` in your shell step in order to install your NodeJS dependencies! See my gist [here](https://gist.github.com/wcheek/384ab30e42b541d6691e2aa2789fa009)

Answer (score 0):

The NodejsFunction construct doesn't require package.json for the lambdas. It can assemble the packages and code part itself from the root package.json. That makes it so powerful IMO.

Comment: Mine do as they have dependencies.

Comment: @Luke This is a good idea.  You don't need multiple `package.json`.  A single `package.json` at the project root -- _which includes your Lambda dependencies_ -- simplifies your setup and reduces potential sources of error.  All your Lambdas can build from the root `package.json` dependencies.